# crontab is not working

Tags: linux, fedora, cron, scp

I am using Linux Fedora. I want to create a crontab with SCP command, but it's not working.

```
[shiv@db2 ~]$ crontab -l
#this is server to server copy...
*/2 * * * * date >> ~/$ scp shiv@127.0.0.1:~/Pictures/foobar.txt  /home/shiv/Desktop/expc/ >> ~/shivraj.logs
```

It will give the following error

```
"/home/shiv/scpcron.txt":4: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the command every half hour?

Comment: The `crontab -l` output is of crontab entries that you successfully installed. The "bad minute" error is from attempting to install a new crontab. It's not clear the error is related to the crontab entry that you've shown. Could you illustrate exactly how you get that error, including the contents of this "/home/shiv/scpcron.txt" file?

Comment: #this is server to server copy...
*/2 * * * * >> scp shiv@127.0.0.1:~/Pictures/foobar.txt  /home/shiv/Desktop/expc/ >> error.logs 2>&1

scp
echo"this file transfer by scp" >> error.logs
#

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the contents of /home/shiv/scpcron.txt? Adding it as a comment doesn't preserve the line breaks in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You command is invalid. You need to seperate the different commands you want to run with a semicolon:

```
*/2 * * * * date >> ~/$; scp shiv@127.0.0.1:~/Pictures/foobar.txt  /home/shiv/Desktop/expc/ >> ~/shivraj.logs
```

(In addition, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you are writing the date to a file named `$`)

Comment: i appreciate ur answers.After editing crontab still its not working & same error. i want to run crontab every 2 min.

Answer (score 0):

Make the big command in to script. Put execution permission. Then call it.

```
sudo vim /usr/bin/mycommand
```

and paste following content.

```
date >> ~/$ scp shiv@127.0.0.1:~/Pictures/foobar.txt  /home/shiv/Desktop/expc/ >> ~/shivraj.logs.
```

Then make is executable.

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/mycommand
```

Then try this command is work or not with by typing it as follows in terminal.

```
/usr/bin/mycommand
```

**If it works, Then add that command to cron.**

Comment: Could you expand this answer a bit. Maybe give an example of what you mean based on the OP scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer. ;)